# How to assign the SSD for file operations in Python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, virtualenv, data-science, spyder

I am currently working with Spyder IDE on a Convolutional Neural Network training project. (Python 3.6 , keras-tensorflow).

My data set is pretty large in means of size and the problem is even though my computer has enough space to store the dataset, it runs out of storage when i run the script.

I have tried to relocate the dataset to my external SSD but my computer still runs out of storage. Then I have tried to create a python virtual environment inside my SSD to run the script from that environment but it was still using my computer's internal drive to store runtime variables.

I need to know if there is a way to tell Python to use my external SSD to store runtime variables instead of my internal drive.

**Code:** [link on codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/5OPmWv)

```
x_train, x_test = [], []
counter = 0
for image_id in y_train.index.values:
    counter = counter + 1;
    image = imageio.imread('/Volumes/Untitled/skin-cancer-mnist-ham10000/Images/{}.jpg'.format(image_id))
    #image = misc.imresize(image, size=TARGET_SIZE, interp='nearest')
    image = normalize(image)
    x_train.append(image)
    if counter%50 == 0:    
        print('Completed processing {} images'.format(counter))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Runtime variables are in memory, not on disk

Comment: Still, as I run the script, the more images read, the less disk space I have. How can I assert python to use external ssd to cache those images there instead of my internal drive?

Comment: Show the code that loads the images

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't handle the formatting in stackoverflow. https://codeshare.io/5OPmWv

Comment: I think you are confusing RAM and hard disk/SSD storage, which are not the same thing. Aspeople have mentioned, variables are stored in RAM memory, and you are probably running out of that.